# how do I add open source API code to an eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, open-source, project

I have to write a java application which I'm putting together using eclipse and it relies on open source code. This application needs to be self-contained, meaning that I'm supposed to create a jar file that has no external dependencies.

I can use the open source code when I reference the jar files in the project's build path, but the idea is to have the actual source code as part of the eclipse project, side-by-side with my code.

The source code can be found here: http://hc.apache.org/, but when I import an existing file system into my project I can't quite get things to work. The packages end up with the wrong names, breaking references, and I can't do anything. Notice that the folder containing the source code has this structure:

```
 httpcomponents-client-4.2.3\
    src\
    httpmime\
    httpclient-osgi
    httpclient-contrib
    httpclient-cache
    httpclient-benchmark
    httpclient
    fluent-hc
```

each of those subfolders has src/main/java/org/apache subfolders.

Can someone please explain how to do this? Am I supposed to import everything one java file at a time?

Comment: If you're using maven to build your project, you could use the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to pull your compiled code and dependent jars together. (Comment because it might not apply to your situation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a tool like [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/), [FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/), [JarJar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/), etc. to create a single-jar application.

As Charlie mentioned, the [Maven Shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) is another choice, particularly if you're already using Maven. If you're not, consider it or another transitive dependency management tool.

<sup>*Some* tool should be used, IMO, and it's more important the more dependencies you have.</sup>

Alternatively you could use a [jar class loader](http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php) and include the jar file in your artifact.

I would most definitely *not* include the *source* of dependencies in your own project.

Comment: @JohnSmith Probably missing the point ;) This sounds more like a Jenkins classpath configuration issue, but *could* be related to version conflicts etc. depending on what the actual symptoms are. I'm not familiar enough with Jenkins to provide specific classpath-related advice, but I'd imagine there's a way to determine them in a reasonable way (ah, assumptions). For example, if there's a mass-classpath-for-everything, some form of package shading might be required to avoid version conflicts.